# silverlight .xap packaging bug (references of reverenced assemblies)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, reference, xap

I encountered this strange issue and was lost for several hours before i found something interesting about how the .xap is packaged.

among several things, i came to know that if my project was named "References", it would not be included in the xap,

and more strange was another problem that if my SL app is referenceing assbly1 project and assbly1 is referencing assbly2, then assbly2.dll will not be included in the xap for the SL app if there are no references to the types of assbly2 in the code behind of assbly1.
code behind is different from xaml, so if you have a user control in you assbly2, and you have only referenced that item in xaml (not code behind)of assbly1, it will not be packaged in SL xap.

any insights...?

Comment: You referenced the usercontrol in assembly #2, but did you actually use it? Unused references will be dropped when the project is built.

Comment: i agree, however the bug is that even if i refer something in xaml, that should be treated as a valid reference which is not how it functions now.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the References thing.
'References' is a reserved name (its a defaultfolder placed in the xap file).

This is interesting because it makes me want to try it myself and see what happens (no errors?).